# <div> has to "delete" it's content on moseover

Tags: html, hover, mouseover

So i have some trouble with a , the mouseover works but i need something more than that, it has to delete it's content when the background changes.

```
#Test01{
background: url(../img/Test01.png);
float: left;
display: block;
height: 297px;
width: 319px;
} 
#Test01:hover {
background: url(../img/Test01hover.png);
}

<div id="Test01"><div id="test01content">lot's of bla bla bla bla bla</div></div>
```

so this div with it's content should be gone when it does it's mouseover.

thx

Comment: You could do that easily using jQuery!

Comment: what code should i use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using CSS, try use Javascript to achieve it,

```
$("#Test01").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("background-image", "url(../img/Test01hover.png)")
   $(this).empty();
});
```

Comment: try again, I missed # in $("#Test01")

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery

```
$("#Test01").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).empty();
});
```